# How to switch user programmatically in windows

Tags: windows, visual-c++, winlogon

I would like to know if there are any API's available to switch users programmatically in windows.My application when provided with user credentials(account name & password) will try to logout any other user logged on and try to login the present user.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The function you are presumably looking for is [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx)

However, you are probably better off using [user impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246062.aspx) in most cases.

Personally, I suspect you are likely better off user neither method and simply using security context of the running user, providing an privileged function via a windows service you wrote specifically for your application

Comment: I realized I made a minor mistake sometime after I posted this answer, LogonUser is part of user impersonantion. I don't know if it is actually possible to login with providing a custom GINA replacement under Windows, and I know MS changed how this worked beginning with Vista - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx

Comment: I'm actually looking for vista and above. I actually wrote a custom credential provider for logging in the user if the user is at logon screen. I wanted to extend it further.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a service to switch user credentials (by methods mentioned in the other answers), and install and run the service as "Administrator". From the logged in user account, you can invoke this service (Which is already running as admin), and make it switch user accounts without the permissions issue (as the service responsible to switching is already running as admin)

Answer (score 0):

Found this one while searching the same topic and it worked for me. By the way it requires admin rights. [SessionUtil.cpp](https://github.com/duncansmart/SessionUtil/blob/master/SessionUtil.cpp)

And in case it gets deleted:

```
// SessionUtil.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

void printError(TCHAR *messageFormat)
{
    LPWSTR pErrorMsg;
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 0, GetLastError(), 0, (LPWSTR)&pErrorMsg, 0, NULL);
    wprintf(messageFormat, pErrorMsg);
    LocalFree(pErrorMsg);
}

void showBalloonTip(const TCHAR* msg)
{
    static bool nidset = false;
    static NOTIFYICONDATA nid = {};

    if (nidset == false)
    {
        nid.cbSize = sizeof(nid);
        nid.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_INFORMATION);

        GUID tipGuid = {0x30375b04, 0x977b, 0x410f, { 0x9e, 0xb7, 0x46, 0xed, 0xb5, 0xf7, 0xf4, 0xe2 }};
        nid.guidItem = tipGuid;

        nid.uFlags = NIF_INFO | NIF_ICON | NIF_GUID;
        nidset = true;
    }

    wcsncpy_s(nid.szInfo, msg, ARRAYSIZE(nid.szInfo));

    Shell_NotifyIcon(nidset ? NIM_MODIFY : NIM_ADD, &nid);

    //Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, &nid) ? S_OK : E_FAIL;
}

int findSession(TCHAR *userToFind)
{
    int sessionId = -1;

    WTS_SESSION_INFO *sessions; 
    DWORD count;
    if (!WTSEnumerateSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1, &sessions, &count))
    {
        printError(L"WTSEnumerateSessions failed: %s\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        WCHAR *sessionUser; 
        DWORD bytes;
        if (!WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, sessions[i].SessionId, WTSUserName, &sessionUser, &bytes))
        {
            printError(L"WTSQuerySessionInformation error: %s\n");
            continue;
        }

#if DEBUG
        wprintf(L"  * Session %d: \n      user: %s\n      state: %d\n      name: %s\n", 
            sessions[i].SessionId, 
            sessionUser, 
            sessions[i].State, 
            sessions[i].pWinStationName);
#endif

        if (sessionUser != NULL && _wcsicmp(userToFind, sessionUser) == 0)
            sessionId = sessions[i].SessionId;

        WTSFreeMemory(sessionUser);

        if (sessionId != -1)
            break;
    }
    WTSFreeMemory(sessions);

    return sessionId;
}

int switchUser(TCHAR *username, TCHAR *password)
{
    int sessionId = findSession(username);

    if (password == NULL)
        password = L"";

    if (sessionId == -1) 
    {   
        std::wstring msg;
        msg.append(L"Session for ")
            .append(username)
            .append(L" not found");

        wprintf(msg.c_str());
        showBalloonTip(msg.c_str());
        return 2;
    }

    if(!WTSConnectSession(sessionId, WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(), password, true))
    {
        wprintf(L"SessionId: %d\n", sessionId);
        printError(L"WTSConnectSession error: %s\n");
        return 2;
    }

    return 0;
}

int logoffUser(TCHAR *userToLogoff)
{
    wprintf(L"Logging off %s\n", userToLogoff);

    int sessionId = findSession(userToLogoff);

    if (sessionId != -1)
    {
        wprintf(L"  session %d\n", sessionId);
        if (!WTSLogoffSession(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, sessionId, TRUE))
        {
            printError(L"WTSLogoffSession failed: %s");
            return 3;
        }
        else 
            wprintf(L"  ...done.\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        std::wstring msg;
        msg.append(L"Session for ")
            .append(userToLogoff)
            .append(L" not found");
        wprintf(msg.c_str());
        showBalloonTip(msg.c_str());

        return 2;
    }

    return 0;
}

void printUsage()
{

    wprintf(
    L"Usage:\n\
    sessionutil switch\n\
    sessionutil switch <username> <password>\n\
    \n\
    sessionutil logoff\n\
    sessionutil logoff <username> [<username2> ...]\n\
    \n\
    sessionutil sleep\n\
    "
    );
}


int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{

    if (argc == 1)
    {
        printUsage();
        return 1;
    }

    if (_wcsicmp(argv[1], L"SWITCH") == 0)
    {
        if (argc > 2)
            return switchUser(argv[2], argv[3]);
        else // go to Switch User screen
            WTSDisconnectSession(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE,  WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, false);
    }
    else if (_wcsicmp(argv[1], L"LOGOFF") == 0)
    {
        if (argc > 2)
        {
            for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++)
                logoffUser(argv[i]);
        }
        else 
        {
            WTSLogoffSession(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, true);
        }
    }
    else if (_wcsicmp(argv[1], L"SLEEP") == 0)
    {
        SetSuspendState(/*bHibernate*/ FALSE, 
            /*bForce*/ FALSE, 
            /*bWakeupEventsDisabled*/ FALSE);
        // Go to Switch User screen
        WTSDisconnectSession(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE,  WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, false);
    }
    else 
    {
        printUsage();
    }
}
```